# Use $inc with $addToSet in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I have a simple function to LIKE posts, on the backend of this web app.**

I'm using `.findByIdAndUpdate` to apply two changes:

- Push the user_id to the post's `_liked_by` array.
- Change the `likes_count` property to reflect the update.

I'm using the `$addToSet` modifier to push the `user_id` to the post's `_liked_by` array to avoid a `user_id` being pushed twice.

But if I just increment the `likes_count` , the function will actually increment it even if the `user_id` was already present at `_liked_by` array and the array remained with the same size.

**Is there a way to pass the `_liked_by` array size in a elegant way as the value for `likes_count` property?**

**Here is the code:**

```js
Post.findByIdAndUpdate({
    _id: post_id
  }, {
    $addToSet: {
      _liked_by: user_id
    },
    // I'd like to have something like...
    $set: {
      likes_count: _liked_by.length
      // ...as If it reads the actual length after the previous $addToSet
      //  Is there an option to do something similar?
    }
  }, {
    new: true
  })
  .then((updated_post) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Post has been liked Successflly!",
      post: updated_post
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "something went wrong | internal server error ",
      err
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter your **`_liked_by`** array in the filter(query) part of the query instead of with [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) and then you can use [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) here to increment **`_liked_by`**  array by 1

```
Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { "_id": post_id, "_liked_by": { "$ne": user_id } },
  {
    "$addToSet": { "_liked_by": user_id },
    "$inc": { "likes_count": 1 }
  },
  { "new": true }
)
```

And you can do using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) as well because we are doing filtering in query part

```
Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { "_id": post_id, "_liked_by": { "$ne": user_id } },
  {
    "$push": { "_liked_by": user_id },
    "$inc": { "likes_count": 1 }
  },
  { "new": true }
)
```

Comment: I like this solution